# D3 - how to fire an on-click function for only a specific group of nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, d3-force-directed

In this [d3 force layout viz project](https://codepen.io/SavanaPope/pen/abLdmbz?editors=1100) I'm trying to remove the user's ability to click on the bigger yellow nodes. I have an on-click, fire the clicknodeControl function,

```
 nodes.append('circle')
  .attr("r", 28)  
  .attr("id", "hoverdots")
  .style("opacity", 0) 
  .style("fill", "#00bedd") 
  .on("click", function(d) { return clicknodeControl(d.group); }) 
  .style("z-index", "10")
  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
  .on("mouseout", mouseout)
```

and then ideally this variable would pass through the clicknode function to one group of nodes but not the other:

```
 var clicknodeControl = d3.scaleOrdinal([`clicknode`, ``]);
```

This does not seem to be working in practice, the clicknode function is not being passed through.

Thanks if anyone has any ideas on this!!

Comment: What is the D3 version you are using?

Comment: I'm using d3 v7

Answer (score 0):

In **D3 V7** mouse event handlers have event as the first argument and datum as the second.

Replace

```
.on("click", function(d) { return clicknodeControl(d.group); })
```

with:

```
.on("click", (_, d) => clicknodeControl(d.group))
```

Comment: Was not able to get this to work. Sorry if it's simple, did the _ mean to add something?

Comment: `-` means there is an argument, but it's not used.

Comment: Tried replacing that line with the new one (and tried _ vs - ) but it didn't work (does not seem to be passing through the clicknode function to a certain group of nodes based on this var:

var clicknodeControl = d3.scaleOrdinal([`clicknode`, ``]);